# How to do a data.table rolling join?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables that I'm trying to merge. One is data on company market values through time and the other is company dividend history through time. I'm trying to find out how much each company has paid each quarter and put that value next to the market value data through time.

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1337)
# data table of company  market values
companies <- 
    data.table(companyID = 1:10,
               Sedol = rep(c("91772E", "7A662B"), each = 5),
               Date = (as.Date("2005-04-01") + months(seq(0, 12, 3))) - days(1),
               MktCap = c(100 + cumsum(rnorm(5,5)),
                          50 + cumsum(rnorm(5,1,5)))) %>%
    setkey(Sedol, Date)

# data table of dividends
dividends <- 
    data.table(DivID = 1:7,
               Sedol = c(rep('91772E', each = 4), rep('7A662B', each = 3)),
               Date = as.Date(c('2004-11-19', '2005-01-13', '2005-01-29',
                                '2005-10-01', '2005-06-29', '2005-06-30',
                                '2006-04-17')),
               DivAmnt = rnorm(7, .8, .3)) %>%
    setkey(Sedol, Date)
```

I believe this is a situation where you could use a data.table rolling join, something like:

```
dividends[companies, roll = "nearest"]
```

to try and get a dataset that looks like

```
       DivID  Sedol       Date   DivAmnt companyID    MktCap
    1:    NA 7A662B       <NA>        NA         6  61.21061
    2:     5 7A662B 2005-06-29 0.7772631         7  66.92951
    3:     6 7A662B 2005-06-30 1.1815343         7  66.92951
    4:    NA 7A662B       <NA>        NA         8  78.33914
    5:    NA 7A662B       <NA>        NA         9  88.92473
    6:    NA 7A662B       <NA>        NA        10  87.85067
    7:     2 91772E 2005-01-13 0.2964291         1 105.19249
    8:     3 91772E 2005-01-29 0.8472649         1 105.19249
    9:    NA 91772E       <NA>        NA         2 108.74579
   10:     4 91772E 2005-10-01 1.2467408         3 113.42261
   11:    NA 91772E       <NA>        NA         4 120.04491
   12:    NA 91772E       <NA>        NA         5 124.35588
```

(note that I've matched the dividends to the company market values by the exact quarter)

But I'm not exactly sure how to execute it. The CRAN pdf is rather vague about what the number is or should be if `roll` is a value (Can you pass dates? Does a number quantify the days forward to carry? the number of obersvations?) and changing `rollends` around doesn't seem to get me what I want.

In the end, I ended up mapping the dividend dates to their quarter end and then joining on that. A good solution, but not useful if I end up needing to know how to perform rolling joins. In your answer, could you describe a situation where rolling joins are the only solution as well as help me understand how to perform them?

Comment: can you describe what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: somehow your code doesn't give the correct data.tables; could provide a `dput()` of `companies` instead?

Comment: I forgot to put the `library(lubridate)` declaration. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: Thanx. Added an answer now. HTH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a rolling join, you may want to use an overlap join with the `foverlaps` function of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# create an interval in the 'companies' datatable
companies[, `:=` (start = compDate - days(90), end = compDate + days(15))]
# create a second date in the 'dividends' datatable
dividends[, Date2 := divDate]

# set the keys for the two datatable
setkey(companies, Sedol, start, end)
setkey(dividends, Sedol, divDate, Date2)

# create a vector of columnnames which can be removed afterwards
deletecols <- c("Date2","start","end")

# perform the overlap join and remove the helper columns
res <- foverlaps(companies, dividends)[, (deletecols) := NULL]
```

the result:

> ```
> > res
>      Sedol DivID    divDate   DivAmnt companyID   compDate    MktCap
>  1: 7A662B    NA       <NA>        NA         6 2005-03-31  61.21061
>  2: 7A662B     5 2005-06-29 0.7772631         7 2005-06-30  66.92951
>  3: 7A662B     6 2005-06-30 1.1815343         7 2005-06-30  66.92951
>  4: 7A662B    NA       <NA>        NA         8 2005-09-30  78.33914
>  5: 7A662B    NA       <NA>        NA         9 2005-12-31  88.92473
>  6: 7A662B    NA       <NA>        NA        10 2006-03-31  87.85067
>  7: 91772E     2 2005-01-13 0.2964291         1 2005-03-31 105.19249
>  8: 91772E     3 2005-01-29 0.8472649         1 2005-03-31 105.19249
>  9: 91772E    NA       <NA>        NA         2 2005-06-30 108.74579
> 10: 91772E     4 2005-10-01 1.2467408         3 2005-09-30 113.42261
> 11: 91772E    NA       <NA>        NA         4 2005-12-31 120.04491
> 12: 91772E    NA       <NA>        NA         5 2006-03-31 124.35588
> ```

---

In the meantime the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) authors  have introduced non-equi joins ([v1.9.8](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md#new-features)). You can also use that to solve this problem. Using a non-equi join you just need:

```
companies[, `:=` (start = compDate - days(90), end = compDate + days(15))]
dividends[companies, on = .(Sedol, divDate >= start, divDate <= end)]
```

to get the intended result.

---

Used data (the same as in the question, but without the creation of the keys):

```
set.seed(1337)
companies <- data.table(companyID = 1:10, Sedol = rep(c("91772E", "7A662B"), each = 5),
                        compDate = (as.Date("2005-04-01") + months(seq(0, 12, 3))) - days(1),
                        MktCap = c(100 + cumsum(rnorm(5,5)), 50 + cumsum(rnorm(5,1,5))))
dividends <- data.table(DivID = 1:7, Sedol = c(rep('91772E', each = 4), rep('7A662B', each = 3)),
                        divDate = as.Date(c('2004-11-19','2005-01-13','2005-01-29','2005-10-01','2005-06-29','2005-06-30','2006-04-17')),
                        DivAmnt = rnorm(7, .8, .3))
```

Comment: When would a rolling join be more appropriate? The documentation seems to say that these sort of things are why rolling joins were created.

Comment: @jks612 Will look into this again. I remember that rolling joins didn't give the desired result, but will look at it again. Hopefully I will be able to that this weekend.

Comment: In, `setkey(dividends, Sedol, dDate, Date2)`, `dDate` is not defined anywhere in your answer.  Presume you meant `divDate`.  Might want to correct this...

Comment: @FXQuantTrader That's a typo, it should have been `divDate` (fixed now). Thx! Also added a non-equi join alternative now.

Comment: non-equi join is so powerful... Thank you for adding the example